# Android tablet browser select box height compatibility issue

Tags: android, css, forms, compatibility

Although my site isn't the best, it's a mash of HTML and isn't even responsive, it works as expected in every browser except for the Android Browser. I have a secreenshot below of the select box in the android browser, and then in every other browser. I'm really not sure how to approach this as I generally work things out in the end with trial and error, and like I said my code really isn't that good!

Any help would really be appreciated :) thanks very much.

***Android*** (using www.modern.ie to test):

[image]

***Other browsers***:

[image]

**The CSS** for the select box:

```
#form .input-select {
background: url(../images/field-bg.png) repeat-x;
height: 30px;
width: 210px;
border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-radius: .2em;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-appearance:menulist;
```

Comment: complete jsfiddle please

Comment: @Harsh - http://jsfiddle.net/8d4v4xkk/

This is how I expect it to look: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/b4efb28a04c658d3e3ef960beebecbe72d7bdab4/macmav_safari_7.0.png

This is how it looks in android:
https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/b4efb28a04c658d3e3ef960beebecbe72d7bdab4/android_Samsung-Galaxy-S-III_4.1_portrait.png

Notice the height of the select box.

Comment: I also encountered this problem couple of months ago on android and also on iOS. I solved it but I forgot how I did it.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez It's such a pain because I can't figure it out. A bit of an anomaly because I believe it's only certain versions of android, but the problem is when you are using paid traffic and someone sees a messed up form, they'll hit the back button. I have already wasted money, which I can see by looking at the bounce rate of android browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements are among the most unreliable parts of HTML/CSS regarding cross-browser rendering consistency. Especially some properties of the box model (`height` in conclusion with `border` or `padding`) [are troublesome](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/27/css-form-elements-problem/).
Citing from that article:

> Developers tried to fix this problem by turning these elements [`input`, `select`] into block-level elements. [...] A common pattern to solve this problem is to avoid the `height` property and instead to use the `font-size` and `padding` properties.

1. A great CSS collection to start with is [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). You should think about using  (parts of) it, to get as much rendering consistency as possible.
2. You are already using `em` as unit for border-radius, for scalability in older browsers, especially IE 6-8, you could go for `em`s for all length units.

I've forked your fiddle, to include those ideas. See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/4v3sm71g/

By the way, Chrome v36.0.x on Android 4.4 doesn't show a difference at all per default.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'l, have a good look over the article. You win the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#form .input-select {
  ? float:right; ?
   clear:right;
}

#form label {
  ? float:left; ?
   clear:left;
}
```

Comment: The issue is the height of the select box on certain android devices, the positioning is a side effect of that I think. If you use www.modern.ie and test this link:http://jsfiddle.net/8d4v4xkk/

You will see that on the android devices the select box is incorrectly displayed, the height isn't what it should be.